# Multi Dem php string to array - comma separated, colon separated array

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I have a string

```
$string = 'S:1,M:1,L:1,XL:1,XXL:1,3XL:1';
```

I want to create an array where

```
$array['S'] = 1;
$array['M'] = 1;
```

I thought i could explode(',', $string);
and then explode(':', $string); again ;-)
but that doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can `explode()` twice, but the second one has to be in a loop:

```
$string = 'S:1,M:1,L:1,XL:1,XXL:1,3XL:1';
// Split on the commas
$sizes = explode(",", $string);
// Output array
$quantities = array();

// Loop over the first explode() result
foreach ($sizes as $size) {
  // Assign each pair to $s, $q
  list($s, $q) = explode(":", $size);
  // And put them onto an array keyed by size
  $quantities[$s] = $q;
}

// This builds an array like:
Array
(
    [S] => 1
    [M] => 1
    [L] => 1
    [XL] => 1
    [XXL] => 1
    [3XL] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = 'S:1,M:1,L:1,XL:1,XXL:1,3XL:1';
$result = array();
foreach (explode(',',$string) as $sub){
  $subAry = explode(':',$sub)
  $result[$subAry[0]] = $subAry[1];
}

var_dump($result);
```

Split it, iterate over the splits, then insert them in to resulting array as a key-value pair.